# Reviewing the same question three times

Tags: support, review

I just finished reviewing this question. Looking at it afterwards, it seems a bit overdone:

[image]

How to cope with this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have selected "No comments needed" when reviewing Low quality posts. Then it would propose deletion but not add any extra comments.

Of course, the review system should actually detect that you have posted a comment or have already flagged it, like how it works for the First posts and Late Answers queue.

Comment: not a bad [tag:feature-request]